# Vertically center four different divs within one

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have four divs that are each one column tables with many rows. They are all floated left with relative positioning and so are all in a row. I want to vertically center them within the div "container". How can I do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
.titlefont{
font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;    
}

div#saucelistdiv{
float:left;
    width:auto;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:auto;
}
div#meatlistdiv{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:auto;
}
div#container{
    height:600px;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:auto;
}
#grainlistdiv{
float:left;
    width:auto;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:auto;
}
div#veggielistdiv{
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:auto;
}
#tablelist{
    border:2px solid;
}
</style>
<body>

<center>
<div id="container">
<div id="saucelistdiv"><table id="tablelist">
    <span class="titlefont">SAUCES</span>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Pizza Sauce" checked="checked" />Pizza Sauce</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Cheese Sauce" />Cheese Sauce</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Barbecue Sauce" />Barbecue Sauce</td></tr>



    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Salsa" />Salsa</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Alfredo Sauce" />Alfredo Sauce</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Taco Sauce" />Taco Sauce</td></tr>



    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Tzatziki (Cucumber) Sauce" />Tzatziki (Cucumber) Sauce</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Chicken Gravy" />Chicken Gravy</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Beef Gravy" />Beef Gravy</td></tr>



    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Ranch Dressing" />Ranch Dressing</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="1000 Island Dressing" />1000 Island Dressing</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Parmesan Peppercorn Dressing" />Parmesan Peppercorn Dressing</td></tr>



    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Spaghetti Sauce" />Spaghetti Sauce</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Chili" />Chili</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Syrup" />Syrup</td></tr>



    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Garlic Butter" />Garlic Butter</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="rbbase" value="Mayonnaise" />Mayonnaise</td></tr>





    </table>
    </div>

<div id="meatlistdiv">
<span class="titlefont">MEATS</span>
    <table class="center" id="tablelist">



      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Sausage" />Sausage<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Pepperoni" />Pepperoni<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Diced Ham" />Diced Ham<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Beef" />Beef<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Bacon" />Bacon<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Lamb" />Lamb<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Bratwurst" />Bratwurst<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Chicken" />Chicken<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Shrimp" />Shrimp<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Crab" />Crab<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Seasoned Beef" />Seasoned Beef<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Corned Beef" />Corned Beef<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Turkey" />Turkey<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Eggs" />Eggs<br /></td></tr>




    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="grainlistdiv">
  <span class="titlefont">GRAINS</span>
    <table class="center" id="tablelist">
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Elbow Macaroni" />Elbow Macaroni<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Spaghetti Noodles" />Spaghetti Noodles<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Oyster Crackers" />Oyster Crackers<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Goldfish" />Goldfish<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Mini Pancakes" />Mini Pancakes<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Pretzels" />Pretzels<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Stuffing" />Stuffing<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Taco Chips" />Taco Chips<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Ramen Noodles" />Ramen Noodles<br /></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>

    <div id="veggielistdiv">
    <span class="titlefont">VEGGIES/OTHER</span>
    <table class="center" id="tablelist">
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Lettuce" />Lettuce<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Tomatoes" />Tomatoes<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Onions" />Onions<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Green Peppers" />Green Peppers<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Green Olives" />Green Olives<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Black Olives" />Black Olives<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Pineapple" />Pineapple<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Sauerkraut" />Sauerkraut<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Broccoli" />Broccoli<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Cauliflower" />Cauliflower<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Jalapeno Peppers" />Jalapeno Peppers<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Pickles" />Pickles<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Cucumbers" />Cucumbers<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Carrots" />Carrots<br /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="cbing" value="Mushrooms" />Mushrooms<br /></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>


     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that if you change your `float:left;` to `display:inline-block;` then you will get the effect that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

vertical aling is only for table. So You can use div as table, 
with this way :

```
div#container
{
    height: 600px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: auto;
    //add these rows
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this with a bit of javascript (this uses JQuery):

```
(document).ready( function () {
    $("#container").children().each( function () {
        var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
        var myHeight = $(this).height();
        $(this).css('top', (parentHeight - myHeight) / 2);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give the div#container a width size and set the margin to auto, it should work:

```
div#container{
    height:600px;
    border:2px solid red;
    width:700px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

*edit - Well, I'm not sure if I actually understood the question, but it does make it look nice :-)